# program for letter n-grams of one word string in python

Tags: python, string, split

I am new to programming. I want to write a program in python which iterates over a one-word string, like "python", and gives me n-grams of the letters. n1 up to n6. I already tried a lot but it didn't work. 
here are some examples:

```
s = "python"
for length in range(0, 13):
    for start in range(27):
        print(s[0:1:2])
```

or:

```
s = "python"
for index, value in enumerate (s):
    print(value)
    ausgabe = 0
    for 
    print (value + 1)
```

It would be nice if I could do it without importing any libraries.
But I already tried NLTK but this was also not helpful.
I read everything in this blog about n-grams, but it was mostly about separating words and I could not adjust the code.
Thank you.

Comment: It would be good to include some examples of expected output.

Comment: It would be good to define "Didn't work, as well" Have a read of [mcve]

Comment: Thank you. I will be more concise in my next questions. Sorry. But I am glad that you answered and helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question wasn't super clear, but I think this is what you're looking for

```
s = "python"    
for nlen in range(1,7):
    for ii in range(len(s)-nlen+1):
        print(s[ii:(ii+nlen)])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it out immediately. I think that it will work.

Comment: I am so grateful that you helped me, because I have been trying to solve this proplem for hours and just could not make it. I was always running into problems. Thank you very much. it worked out pretty well!!!

Comment: My I upvote is not for others to see because I am a newbee. But I upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

```
def create_ngrams(word, n):

    # Break word into tokens
    tokens = [token for token in word]

    # generate ngram using zip
    ngrams = zip(*[tokens[i:] for i in range(n)])

    # concat with empty space & return
    return [''.join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]
```

example: `create_ngrams('python', 2)`

```
tokens = ['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']

ngrams = zip(*[tokens[0:], tokens[1:]])
       = zip(['p','y','t','h','o','n'], ['y','t','h','o','n'])
       = ('p','y'),('y','t'),('t','h'),('h','o'),('o','n')

return ['py', 'yt', 'th', 'ho', 'on']
```

Comment: Sorry, this was my first time asking something and I didn't think about other people reading it. But I will do it better next time. Thanks a lot for your answer. This all has helped me a lot. Also reading other posts (as you said) is very helpful.